# Get UID from expired Firebase auth token?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

For a valid token, we can call `admin.auth().verifyIdToken(...)`. We have a specific case where the token we receive may have expired, but it is not sensitive data so we'd still like to determine the UID behind the expired token. `verifyIdToken()` throws an exception when the token has expired. Is it possible to determine the UID behind an expired token as well as determine when it expired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode the ID token using any JWT library, and check the `sub` claim.